# Obtaining maps that contain location with 2+ US states (cities, etc.) with get_map (location as a vector)

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, latitude-longitude, ggmap

Concept of ggmap seems clear to me:

1. Use `get_map` to obtain a map at a certain location at a certain spatial zoom.
2. Use `ggmap() + ggplot()` to combine map image with `ggplot` graphics.

The challenge at the moment lies in step 1 and, precisely, `location` parameter. Besides a longitude/latitude pair `get_map` accepts a character string, but no vector. It seems that there is no easy way to obtain a map that includes two or more states, or two or more cities.

Thus, to have a function that draws arbitrary number of (presumably adjacent) US states there is no shortcut but to go through elaborate process of geocoding each state and calculating optimal location and zoom (also not sure how).

Comment: A lot of us think it is your responsibility to provide code that loads the relevant packages, and then accesses the shapefiles to be used, and finally sets up a test case to test with.

Comment: I revised the question to avoid steering it towards policy/conventions/agreement discussions. I appreciate your opinion though.

Answer (score 0):

as you can find out here - http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-1/kahle-wickham.pdf - there is the way to put shapefile into ggmap.

All you need to do is:

```
# read data into R (for example - your states)
shapefile <- readShapeSpatial(’tr48_d00.shp’,proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
# convert to a data.frame using fortify function
data <- fortify(shapefile)
#and plot your data using qmap or ggmap
qmap(’texas’, zoom = 6, maptype = ’satellite’) + geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), data = data,colour = ’white’, fill = ’black’, alpha = .4, size = .3)
```

Comment: So I presume that concrete shapefile has to include those states (or cities, or whichever multiple geo artifacts I deal with), right?

Comment: yes, you're right;) Of course, you also need to change qmap code a little bit - from 'texas' to your area, change zoom, etc.

Comment: I guess I need to revise my question since the whole point is find approach to parameterized list of artifacts (maybe restrict them to states or cities within US).

Comment: right now I am taking approach of `geocode`ing each artifact from the list and then taking means of lat/lon, after that manually adjusting zoom. Basically I am looking for solution in that direction.